# R function applied on data frame grouped by multiple factors

Tags: r

I have a data frame called subdata, with a dimension of 10299 x 81. Column 1 called "Subject" and column 2 called "Activity". I want to calculate the average of each column grouped by "Subject" and "Activity".

Here are the functions I tried and none of them seems work so far. Finally I used colwise(mean) function, it seems work. I am new to R and just learned `sapply`, `lapply`, `tapply` functions and it seems mean function works in columns.

Can anyone help me explain what does these error or warning message mean and if there a way to make theses functions work?

**Use lapply function:**

```
newdata<- subdata[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = c("Subject","Activity")]
```

The error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(subdata, , lapply(.SD, mean), by = c("Subject",  : 
unused argument (by = c("Subject", "Activity"))
```

**Use by function:**

```
newdata<-by(subdata, list(subdata$Subject, subdata$Activity), mean)
```

I got warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

**Then I tried ddply in plyr package**

```
ddply(subdata, .(Subject, Activity), mean)
```

I got the same warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(piece, ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA 0
```

**Finally I used colwise(mean)function, it seems work**

```
newdata<-ddply(subdata, .(Subject, Activity), colwise(mean))
```

Comment: with your last option, try `numcolwise(mean)` instead of `colwise(mean)`

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat difficult to be certain with a representative sample of your dataset.  Let's create some data to work with.

```
# Create some random demo data
subdata <- data.frame(Subject = rep(seq(5), each=4), 
                     Activity = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 10), v1=rnorm(20), v2=rnorm(20))
```

Your first attempt I am not even sure where to start.  It appears you are trying to subset your dataframe with the output of a list which already seems strange.  You should abandon this attempt.

Your `by` statement is providing an error about non-numeric data.  This is because the `by` function isn't that smart.  You need to only provide the columns to be analyzed and then the indices (i.e. your factor columns).

```
by(subdata[,-c(1,2)], list(subdata$Subject, subdata$Activity), function(x) colMeans(x))
```

Althought you probably want to `rbind` this output and reassign rownames to correspond to groups.  However, for this purpose it may be best to just use something `aggregate` to avoid such extra computation.

```
aggregate(subdata[,-c(1,2)], list(subdata$Subject, subdata$Activity), mean)
```

Your `ddply` statements are close but as I suggested above you should use `numcolwise` to summarize over your `numeric` columns.

```
library(plyr)
# summarize over all numeric columns
ddply(subdata, .(Subject, Activity), numcolwise(mean))
```